# How can I do a live filter with tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to do a similar filter that is on tabulator homepage. I think I'm not referencing something that I should be.  The error I'm seeing in the console is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at index.html:110

Here's what is at 110

```js
$("#tabulator-controls input[name=feature]").on("keyup", function(){
    table.setFilter( "feature", "like", $(this).val())
});
```

The entire code: https://pastebin.com/szAiwPQZ

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the reference to jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest updating your version of Tabulator. version 3.2 is almost 3 years old at this point. things have come a very long way since then. there are features specifically for live filtering in the later versions.

There is now the ***headerFilterLiveFilter*** option

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", headerFilter:"input", headerFilterLiveFilter:true}
```

See the [Column Header Filter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/filter#header) Docs for more info

Comment: Thanks Oli.  I'm running the latest, but don't really like the header filtering.  IMO it clutters the table